# c# MailMessage custom headers - using System.Net.Mail;

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, mailmessage

Here is my method for testing MailMessage headers :

```
   private void Send_Email(string smtp_server, int port, string display_name, string from, string to, string subject, string html_body, string sender_email, string sender_password)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, display_name, Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.To.Add(to);

            mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Subject = subject;

            mail.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "Reply-To__ <" + from + ">");
            mail.Headers.Add("Sender", from);
            mail.Headers.Add("Return-Path", from);
            mail.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");

            string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            mail.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=--" + boundary);

            //mail.Headers.Add("", Environment.NewLine);
            //mail.Headers.Add("", Environment.NewLine);

            //mail.Headers.Add("", "--" + boundary);
            //mail.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            //mail.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
            //mail.Headers.Add("", Environment.NewLine);
            //var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html_body);
            //var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            //mail.Headers.Add("", base64.ToString());
            //mail.Headers.Add("", "--" + boundary);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender_email, sender_password);
            smtp.Host = smtp_server;
            smtp.Port = port;
            smtp.Timeout = 60000;

            smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("sending email was canceled");
                }
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("sending email was failed -> Error : " + e.Error.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("email was sent successfully");
                }

                mail.Dispose();
            };

            try
            {
                smtp.SendAsync(mail, null);
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sending email was failed, SmtpException -> Error : " + exp.ToString());

                mail.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

In php your hands are free and can make headers and mail structure very well,
Take a look at this example :
http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/01/send-php-mail-with-attachment
I want to do something like php in .Net and make my mail structure using with headers.
But errors in my codes are about these lines :

> mail.Headers.Add("", "blo blo blo");

And **Error** :

> The name part can not be empty...

How can i bypass that error and create every peace of my mail using with headers :
such as -> **Body** - **Attachments** - etc

---

After answer to my question i will figure out how can i combine multiple **Content-Types** :
such as -> **html** - **plain/text** - **octet** - etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this falls under RFC 2822, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2:

> 2.2. Header Fields
>
> Header fields are lines composed of a field name, followed by a
> colon    (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF.  **A
> field    name MUST be composed of printable US-ASCII characters (i.e.,
> characters that have values between 33 and 126, inclusive), except
>
> colon.**  A field body may be composed of any US-ASCII characters,
> except for CR and LF.  However, a field body may contain CRLF when
> used in header "folding" and  "unfolding" as described in section
> 2.2.3.  All field bodies MUST conform to the syntax described in    sections 3 and 4 of this standard.

Seems like empty string is not allowed.

Using a 5 hour SMTP timeout is excessive. A range 5 seconds to 60 seconds is more reasonable.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Is there a way to view mail headers and work on them? In Chrome or FF or another way?

Comment: Seems like you are falling into the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: So sorry for this comment and my prev comment's question is not a stackoverflow.com question and this is why i asked it in comments!

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The following list of mail headers should **not** be added using the
>   Headers property and any values set for these headers using the
>   Headers property will be **discarded** or **overwritten** when the message is
>   sent:
>
> ```
> Bcc
>
> Cc
>
> Content-ID
>
> Content-Location
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding
>
> Content-Type
>
> Date
>
> From
>
> Importance
>
> MIME-Version
>
> Priority
>
> Reply-To
>
> Sender
>
> To
>
> X-Priority
> ```

Comment: so what is the benefit of headers property man? i did n't mentioned on that MSDN link -> Don't set these!!!!

Comment: My understanding is that _some_ headers could be set using the `Headers` property, but not all because there are specific properties for those already.

Comment: also some properties in MailMessage Class are Read-Only. What is this horrible class?

Comment: BTW, the text i posted come from the MSDN link. So, it DOES say, Don't set these...:O)

Comment: The properties that are read-only normally must be set through the corresponding constructor.